# How to brute force a tree of 'yes/no' decisions?

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to solve a puzzle. But I simply don't know what kind of code is required for it. The problem is an exponential one.

**Description:**

The Player walks/runs one step at a time. Sometimes there will be a decision to be made; that is a yes/no question. Once the question is answered, the player continues walking until the next decision/question is reached. Continue this until the total distance is covered.

[image: The problem is exactly like this.]

The problem is I want to see every possible route through this (many python lists such as ['y','y','n','y','n']). Here is the code I have written so far: (the Player is in a `Player()` class, I have removed it because it is unimportant here.)

```
class Solver(object):
    """ Solver object. """

def __init__(self, field):
    self.field = field
    self.dinc = 113
    self.distance = 128

def take_step(self, player):
    """ Takes a step and records players route. """
    # Adds 0 if there is no decision to be made on this step
    # Adds 1 if there is a decision to be made on this step

    player.run(self.dinc)
    if self._is_decision_time(player):
        player.route.append((player.step_id, 1))
    else:
        player.route.append((player.step_id, 0))

def next_decision(self, player):
    """ Accepts a player object. Walks until reaches next decision. """
    while not self._is_decision_time(player):
        self.take_step(player)
    self.display_stats(player)

def say_no(self, player):
    """ Simulates a no response. Resets danger. Updates route with decision. """
    player.route[-1] = (player.step_id, 'n')
    player.danger = 0
    print 'no!'

def say_yes(self, player):
    """ Simulates a yes response. Updates route with decision. """
    player.route[-1] = (player.step_id, 'y')
    print 'yes!'
```

The solution of what I'm looking for is like this:

- Walk until a question is reached
- Make a copy of the route
- On route A say Yes
- On route B (the copy) say No

Route A:
repeat what is above (this forks another two routes)

Route B:
repeat what is above (this forks another two routes)

Using the code I have so far, it is something like:

```
route_a = Player()
solver = Solver()

# walk until a battle is reached
solver.next_decision(route_a)
# make a copy of the route (there are now two routes A + route B)
route_b = copy.deepcopy(route_a)

# on route A say 'yes'
solver.say_yes(route_a)
# on route B say 'no'
solver.say_no(route_b)
# walk until the next decision is reached
solver.next_battle(route_a)
solver.next_battle(route_b)
# Then?
```

This problem is exponential, because at each decision the route forks into two more routes. I need all of the possibilities; I happen to know there are less than 512 possibilities so a computer can solve it in an instant.

Each route will be stored in a Player.route instance (as a list, eg: ['y','y','n','y'])

I just have no idea how to solve a problem like this programmatically. I would appreciate some ideas as to how to structure code to solve a problem like this.

Comment: What do you know about backtracking?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, such a data structure -- a binary tree -- is used in order to just avoid the exponential problem you mentioned. Or, in other words, the supposed list of `'y'` and `'n'` will grow exponentially, but usually you don't need it, because you have the binary tree. You know that you get each way by a yes-or-no question.

But, if you want to print the list you were asking for, do it like in this pseudo-code (since I'm lost to C++, I still can't program in Python ;-) )

```
def recurse(node, s=''):
    if node == end_node:
        print s
        return

    recurse(node.left,  s + 'n')
    recurse(node.right, s + 'y')
```

Then invoke the function starting at the root or head node, i.e. `recurse(root_node)`.

Comment: `function → def`, `x{} → x:`, `-> → .`, remove the word `string` and you've got Python. You'd also want to remove the semicolons and the parentheses on the `if`, but it'll run anyway :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick introduction! :)

Comment: Also note that while the tree is highly compressible, a simple implementation of a binary tree will still have ~2ⁿ nodes.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a fairly easy job for recursion and you already have a pretty simple tree structure.  Perhaps you should just migrate the decision process into an explicit tree structure and implement a recursive traversal of the nodes?  That's probably the most prudent solution given what it looks like you're trying to do.  I guess you're looking for "brute force"... but the alternate iterative solution would be a lot less elegant (and harder to write).

Answer (score 0):

A naive, but probably a suitable way to generate permutations like this is to run through numbers `0..512`, convert them to binary (with right padding) and treat zeroes as 'No' and ones as 'Yes'. Nine bits is enough for 512 values, so generate a string like this:

```
'{0:0>9b}'.format(123)
```

Comment: This will work only if you have exactly 8 yes-no questions in each branch. Otherwise one needs to have another binary field which determines whether a node is an end-node.

Comment: @davidhigh: yup, good point. By the question I think this is the case but in general case the recursive crawler is both robust and simple.